# Where should I save the data?

Tags: android, sql

I am trying to create an android app that will have approximately 10000 problems with each question having 4 options .I was thinking of creating an SQLiteDatabase for storing questions.But creating each entry /question inside an android app seems an hectic task ,but then I thought of creating the database outside the app and importing it but in both case the app size I think will be very large .I wanted to know is there a better way to deal with this problem ?

Comment: if it's just text in you questions, this won't be very large. with aprox. 6 letters per word and 10 words per question/answer combination (for english language) this will only be around 300 KB of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Firebase as a backend for your application. The realtime database stores data in JSON format and has very easy to implement methods.

This way, you don't need to worry about the networking aspect of having an online database and you can store as much data as you want.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/